# PHP/CODEIGNITER:Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I got this error and cant fix it help me please

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/auth.php

Line Number: 20

and this is my code:
 The line 20 starts at if ($user->mail){

```
if ($user->mail) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("Success","You Are now logged in");

            $_SESSION['user_logged'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['username']=$user->username;
        }
        else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "No Account exists in Database");
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is code???

Comment: Are you sure `$user` is an object? How is it instantiated?

Comment: `$user` is likely `null` or `false`, just look where you get the value of that variable.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of the error message is that `$user` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Well as the error is self explanatory, you are using:

```
$user->mail
$user->username
```

But according to the error $user is not an object and as such you can not get property of non-object. So try to figure out what exactly are you doing with $user, returning an object or an array.